# OpenGL scaling GUI

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am developing a 2D game. My own monitor is 1080p, so the GUI is based on a monitor that is 1080p. This causes the GUI to look bad whenever the monitor has a resolution that is smaller then 1080p. I realize that this is maybe not so correct programming, but I'm too far into the development for changing the whole GUI.

For me an obvious solution to this problem was to simply add a `glScalef(scale, scale, 1)` at the beginning of my render code. This worked, but looked hideous. The textures weren't properly scaling, and text looked horrible as well.

My next thought was to render the whole scene onto a quad (the quad being 1920x1080), and then scale that quad to the size of the monitor. Kind of like how downsampling works. The problem is that I have no idea how to implement this in OpenGL. I have seen people do it before, so I know it must be possible, however I can't find any tutorials that properly explain how to do this.

**edit**

This is the problem:
[image: the problem]

notice the blueish and orange lines (only 1 pixel wide) on the left picture. The right is the original and the desired effect (only I want it downscaled of course).

here is my code that I used for the normal downscaling:

```
// the rendering screen size (1080p)
public static final Dimension RENDERING_SCREEN_SIZE = new Dimension(1920, 1080);
// a temporary fixed screen size that is commonly used by laptops
public static final Dimension SCREEN_SIZE = new Dimension(1366, 768);
private static float scale = 1.0F;

//...//

public static final void initialize() {
    //...//

    scale = (float) (SCREEN_SIZE.getWidth() / RENDERING_SCREEN_SIZE.getWidth());       
}

public static final void startRenderLoop() {
    while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();
        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        GL11.glScalef(scale, scale, 0);

        // render the scene

        Display.sync(60);
        Display.update();
    }

    Display.destroy();
}
```

Please note that the quads seen are *not* colored quads, they are textured quads.

**/edit**

Any help with this or another solution to my downscaling is much appreciated.

Comment: How would the result be any different? Rendering a scaled scene or rendering a scaled quad would surely look the same. Actually, the latter approach would look worse - you'd need to render the scene to a texture and apply that texture to the quad, so you'd be scaling pixels (well, texels) instead of vector (polygon) data.

Comment: Because than it doesn't actually scale the individual quads the GUI is made up of. I have a lot of textures that when the quad scales, the textures uv coordinates seem not to be the same anymore

Comment: I think that we're going to need to [see an example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to really understand what your problem is.

Comment: An example of my code or the problem with GUI scaling (like a screenshot)?

Comment: Ideally both! More information is always helpful.

Comment: http://puu.sh/gCKOf/b31be5c76f.png that is a screenshot showing the essence of the problem. Notice on the left (the downscaled version) there is a small orange line (which can be found in the texture as well). Also the gray lines. The right is the original

Comment: Please [edit your post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29080343/edit) to include any screenshots (and code, if possible).

Answer (score 0):

Developing GUI isn't an easy task even for skilled programmers. To implement GUI scaling you need to decide how it would look. Do you want to scale all elements for given dimensions or only some of them? Do you want to have bad looking elements cause you scaled them to dimension with another width to height ratio? If you want to manage what you want to scale and what not - you should scale each element on the screen. As i can see you just want to render whole screen to a texture and then apply it to scaled quad each frame. FBO (Frame buffer object) should help you to render scene to texture. And last step - scaling. If you scale it somehow wrong - you'll get artifacts like that. If that's so sad - try to play with texture parameters such as filtering mode. The actual implementation now in your hands. Good luck!